# What is the conversion ratio of linear to angular momentum when a ball hits a rod in space?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, rotational-kinematics

If the ball hits the rod at 90 degrees then the rod will start spinning, while also following the original trajectory of the ball. On what factors does the ratio between the two types of momentum depend? What is the mathematical relation and how do I calculate it? I know that if the bar is pivoted in the center then all the linear momentum of the ball is transfered to the angular momentum of the rod. Can someone explain why?

Comment: "I know that if the bar is pivoted in the center then all the linear momentum of the ball is transfered to the angular momentum of the rod." What you think you know is generally wrong. It depends on the masses and moments of inertia, how much of the linear/angular momentum transferred. For (partly) inelastic impacts, it also depends on plasticity of the materials. In short: the topic is way too wide to be answered here. A drawing may help in narrowing the question.

Comment: I do not mean that the momentum of the ball is fully transfered to the rod, as in the ball comes to a stop and the rod starts moving. I'm asking that ,from the momentum that was transfered to the rod, how much of it goes into translation, and how much of it goes into rotation. In a pivoted rod, translation would be null, while all the momentum transfered would go into rotation. I am unsure what part of my question is too vague . Did this explanation help?

Answer (score 0):

If the strike is at 90 degrees, and the rod was at rest, then you can conserve momentum in one direction. If the ball bounces off, the rod will rotate about its center of mass;  if not, the rotation will be about the new center of mass. You can choose a reference point for conservation of angular momentum (in the plane of motion). For each mass (before and after the collision) the angular momentum is mvR + Iω where (R) is measured perpendicular to the line of motion from the reference point, and (ω) is the angular velocity of the mass about its own center.  As a vector, (ω) should be perpendicular to the plane of  motion. If you know that the collision is elastic, then you can also use conservation of energy. For this type of collision, linear and angular momentum are calculated separately.